# Bash script for variable assignment using ||

Tags: conda, zsh

I am trying to use bash script to assign value to variable IF env is not present:

```
env_available=$(source activate .conda/envs/$CONDA_ENV_37) || 'create'
```

But I m getting this error.

Not a conda environment: /.caches/.conda/envs
zsh: command not found: create

Expected result: If env is not present env_available = 'create'.
Current result: If env is not present its throwing error as command not found.

Comment: `env_available=$(source activate .conda/envs/$CONDA_ENV_37) || env_available=create`

Comment: Is the `activate` script supposed to modify the shell environment? I ask because the commands in `$( )` execute in a subshell, so any environment changes will be local to that subshell, and will vanish when the subshell exits.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` but the error message is coming from `zsh`.